# How to add a proper reference to a dependency so that it works on everybody's machine (including a build server)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, ndbunit

I am trying to setup an automatic test of my MVC4 application using [NDbUnit](https://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) in Jenkins. On my local machine I have references to `NDbUnit.core` and `NDbUnit.SqlClient` that I added in the solution explorer by clicking the References folder, then 'Add reference' and then adding them from disk. They work like a charm.

However, when I commit the solution to the repository which triggers the automatic build on the Jenkins build server, the build fails. The error messages look like this for both files:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: 
Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "NDbUnit.Core". Check to make 
sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get 
compilation errors. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Project\workspace\Project\Project.csproj]
      For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
      Considered "..\packages\NDbUnit_1.6.7.0\NDbUnit.Core.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

When I make a fresh checkout and try to build the solution on my own machine, I get the same message that the reference could not be resolved. The two files are however in the References folder, they just don't work (unlike the others they have an exclamation mark symbol next to them). Only when I reference them from my own machine they work again.

This madness has cost me a lot of points in the continuous integration game. I hope someone can explain to me how I can properly reference the `.dll`'s so that they work everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you need to do 2 things to make sure the assemblies are available:

1. Check the binaries in to source control.  Some source control systems might push back at first since they are a binary format, but you can usually force it.  (I know with TFS, if you do `tf add Foo.*`, it will skip the DLL so you need to do `tf add Foo.dll` explicitly.)
2. Make sure you're referencing the DLL from the correct relative path.  This is specified as the HintPath in the project file, e.g.

   ```
   <Reference Include="DllThatYouReference">
     <HintPath>../../relative/path/to/DllThatYouReference.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   ```

The alternative to doing this manually is to use a package manager such as [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/).  When you install a Nuget package, it will configure the HintPath for that reference in the project file.  You can also configure it to [install the necessary packages at build time](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) if they're not already available, which adds a little bit of compile time in exchange for not having to check in the DLL files.

> The two files are however in the References folder, they just don't work (unlike the others they have an exclamation mark symbol next to them).

The References folder isn't actually a folder, it's a list of all the assemblies that your project references.  This information is found from the project file, so they will show up regardless of whether the files exist locally.  The exclamation point indicates that the files are missing (or can't be resolved for some other reason, but from your error message they're probably missing).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With NuGet the files were indeed added properly. I did not use it at first since I could not find the files for some reason.

Comment: Cheking in the binaries to source control seems to be a bad idea and a workaround at best?

Comment: @AndersLindén If you're using git, I would be very careful about checking in binaries if they change regularly, as that would bloat the repository over time.  Otherwise, checking in binaires is probably the safest way to make sure your dependencies are available.  Who knows which package managers will still be actively hosted in 5 or 10 years when your project is still running and requires maintenance.

Comment: @AndersLindén You could also use packages hosted on your own feed so that you have reliable copies of your dependencies, but that should have its own backup plan in place (source control being one option, though again, git is probably a poor choice).